# API do Google Maps

Tags: api, google-maps

Estou com a seguinte situação:

A localização geográfica do meu País é:

```
longitude de 73°59’32 (A OESTE)
longitude 34°47’30 (A Leste)
latitude 5°16’20 (Ao Norte)
latitude 33°45’03 (Ao sul)
```

Estou utilizando o exemplo disponibilizado pela Google chamado "Simple Markers".

No  script abaixo (presente no exemplo citado acima), como faço para exibir somente o mapa do Brasil?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Simple markers
    
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }

```
  function initMap() {
    var myLatLng = {lat: -16.461, lng: -130.012};

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 4,
      center: myLatLng
    });

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatLng,
      map: map,
      title: 'Computacao Evolucionaria!'
    });
  }
</script>
<script async defer
```

Já tentei de tudo, mas não consigo.

Meu objetivo é fazer uma busca somente nessa área. Ou seja, quero restringir o mapa por região. Nesse caso, "O Brasil"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para mostrar apenas uma específica área, sabendo seus limites, utilize a API LatLngBound, como no exemplo https://jsfiddle.net/t30y8vwL/

```js
var map;

function initMap() {
    var myLatLng = {lat: -16.461, lng: -130.012};

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 5,
      center: myLatLng
    });
    
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var limits = [];
    
    limits.push({lat: 5.2719444444444, lng: -59.7875}); //Norte
    limits.push({lat:-33.751944444444, lng: -52.452777777778}); //Sul
    limits.push({lat: -6.6783333333333, lng: -33.207222222222}); //lest
    limits.push({lat: -6.4641666666667, lng: -72.009444444444}); //Oeste
    
    limits.forEach(function(l){
     bounds.extend(l);
    })

    map.fitBounds(bounds);
    
    markers = limits.map(function(l){
     return new google.maps.Marker({
        position: l,
        map: map,
        title: 'Computacao Evolucionaria!'
      });
    })
  }
```

Dessa forma o zoom e o centro do mapa são alterados para um arranjo com os limites definidos.

Comment: Muito Obrigado! Funcionou perfeitamente.

Comment: Tranquilo. Caso você precise descobrir as latitudes e longitudes, ou seja os limites, pode usar esta página aqui: http://mapas.webdias.com.br/ é só clicar no mapa para encontrar a latitude e a longitude.